# How to check if a user is logged in to Google & display a link/button if he is not?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am writing my very first Google App Engine application, mostly as a learning experience, its a sort of Pastebin very simple... I dont want to deal with spam so figured that requiring users to log in would be a safe enough choice.
At this point this is what I want:

- Visitor sees main page, if visitor is logged in to Google he sees the "Save paste" button, if user is not logged in he sees a link/button to log in to Google

I have read a few articles and tutorials ([1](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview)) but they give me the idea that I would be locking everyone out except a few allowed ones or that this sort of authentication is to manage my application instead of just checking if a user is logged in or not.

If on the other hand you can suggest a spam checker or similar, that is easy to implement please let me know.

I find particularly confusing that we have to define the type of authentication when creating the app, since this is going to be implemented by code I dont understand this.

So to summarize: How can I check if a user is logged in to Google and display a link/button if he is not?

Note: Im using [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Users API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview) you mention is just what you need. Just follow the example provided in that page.

You fetch the user, if the user is not null you show the Save paste button, you should also set the url of the save paste action to require login. If the user is null you show the login url. In case the user is not logged in a login page will be shown.

There are three types of authentication systems:

1. Google Accounts: available to anyone with a Google Account (can even be a non gmail account) This is probably the option you want to use.
2. Google Apps: available only to a specific Google Apps domain (example yourcompany.com)
3. Open Id: available to anyone with an OpenId identity (Google, Yahoo, MySpace, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if User is logged in to google or not, have them login to your app using google Oauth api. You will have more controller over the user in this approach.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.