# Programmatically login into google account in c#

Tags: c#, google-signin

Is it possible to programmatically sign in to my Google account through my web site in c#?

Just as a user would do manually by entering their email and password here:
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin

By this I mean, on page load, the code would check to see if the user is logged in, and if not, then log them in.

I would really appreciate any help anyone has.

Comment: Duplicate::http://stackoverflow.com/a/11651195/763026

Comment: Its not a duplicate because I actually need the site to log the user in

Comment: Whats the non-phishing use case for needing the user to put their Google password into your site instead of using oauth or sending them to the "real" login page?

Comment: It's not the users account I need to sign into, its my own, and its just the one account. I want to display data from my account onto onto my website.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses OAuth for authentication.  You need to include an oauth client in your application in order for the user to login to their google account.  There are many oauth packages for .NET, i use [DotNet OpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/)

related:
[OAuth C# Library for Google, Yahoo! Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380473/oauth-c-sharp-library-for-google-yahoo-twitter)

Comment: I've followed the example: fryan0911.com/2010/09/use-google-openid-authentication-in.html. It uses the DotNetOPenAuth library, I've noticed that this only works intermittently and requires the user log on to request access which is fine, but the user is still required to log back in after logging out, even though they have requested and been approved access. Is there a way for the site to log the user in programmatically permanently after they have requested and been approved access?

Comment: This is all you can do.  This is feature of the auth scheme, it ensures that users are always explicitly allowing an application to act on their behalf, it protects both the users and the service provider (Google, in this case) but it comes at the cost of development complexity, and a minor inconvenience on the users behalf (having to log in multiple times).

Comment: Slightly disappointing to hear that, but that's for the guidance!